# Angular 5 full screen immovable, non stretching background image

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

I have an angular 5 app with 2 nested router outlets and I'd like to add a background image that covers the whole page at all times.
So if the user starts scrolling, the content should be scrolled over but the background image should always fill the whole background and not move at all (and not change size or stretch), regardless of how deep down the nested router outlets the navigation goes.

In addition I want to change the picture depending on the screen size. (@desktop, @mobile)

So I got:

```
<style>
   body, html {
     height: 100%;
   }
   .bg {
     background-image: url("backgroundImage.png");

     height: 100%;

     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
   }
</style>
<body>
   <div class="bg">
     <app-root></app-root>
   </div>
</body>
```

This works as far as it initially fills the screen with the background image, however if the nested components grow too big and the user starts scrolling, the image is scrolled away with the rest of the content.

What could I add to make it immovable and always fullscreen?

Comment: considered using bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: Have you tried `background-attachment: fixed;` ?

Comment: @Callum That did it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `background-attachment: fixed;` will do the job.